# Can't texture and transform at the same time

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, opengl-4

I have accomplished to make a coloured square, that is rotating around the centre. And can also texture the square. But when I combine the two I only get a rotating black square.

In the fragment shader I can exchange between showing the colours defined in the vertex array and showing the image I chose for texture. This by interchanging the comments of the two lines in main. Both work fine when not rotating:

```
#version 450 core
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
void main()
{
   //   color = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
   color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord); 
}
```

In the Vertex shader I can chose to rotate or not by interchanging the commenting of the `gl_Position` lines:

```
#version 450 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform*vec4(position, 1.0f);
//  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
    TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

And the code to drive these:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Positions          // Colors           // Texture Coords
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Top Right
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Left
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Top Left
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3, // First Triangle
    1, 2, 3, // Second Triangle
};

GLuint VBO, VAO, indexBuffer;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glCreateBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glCreateBuffers(1, &VBO);

glNamedBufferStorage(VBO, sizeof (vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
glNamedBufferStorage(indexBuffer, sizeof (indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

// Create index buffer
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(VAO, indexBuffer);

//position
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 0, 0);

//color
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 1);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (3 * sizeof ( GLfloat))); // relative offset is the size in bytes until the first "color" attribute
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 1, 0);

//texture
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 2);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (6 * sizeof ( GLfloat))); // relative offset is the size in bytes until the first "color" attribute
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 2, 0);

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 0, VBO, 0, 8 * sizeof ( GLfloat)); // The stride is the number of bytes between hver vertex

// ===================
// Texture
GLuint texture = 0;
int width = 0, height = 0;
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture);

unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image("image2.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);

std::cout << "Bredde: " << width << "   Højde: " << height << "\n";
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextureStorage2D(texture, 1, GL_RGBA2, width, height);
glTextureSubImage2D(texture, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateTextureMipmap(texture);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
glBindTextureUnit(0, 0);

// Game loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ourShader.Use();

    glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0);
    transform = glm::rotate(transform, (GLfloat) glfwGetTime() * 5.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    const auto Textureloc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture");
    glBindTextureUnit(Textureloc, texture);

    // Get matrix's uniform location and set matrix
    const GLint transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "transform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

    std::cout << "Transform location: " << transformLoc << "\n";
    std::cout << "Texture location: " << Textureloc << "\n";

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTextureUnit(0, 0);

    // Swap the screen buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

I'm afraid I have mixed up some DSA stuff with non-DSA stuff. Therefore the post in: [Using glBindVertexArray in update loop in DSA code or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117299/using-glbindvertexarray-in-update-loop-in-dsa-code-or-not)

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: By the way. Can somebody with the priviledges maybe add a DSA tag for opengl4-stuff? The current DSA-tag is for encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse the location of the texture sampler uniform variable and the texture unit.

The location of the uniform variable is an active program resource, which can be get by [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml):

```cpp
const auto Textureloc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture");
```

But you can choose a [texture unit](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units) a texture unit, and bind the texture to this unit.
Then you have to set the texture unit index value to the texture sampler uniform:

e.g.

```cpp
GLuint unit = 3;
glBindTextureUnit(unit, texture); 
glUniform1i(Textureloc, unit);
```

Note, the texture unit is the link between the shader program and the texture object.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 7.10 Samplers; page 154](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf):

> Samplers are special uniforms used in the OpenGL Shading Language to identify
>   the texture object used for each texture lookup. The value of a sampler indicates the texture image unit being accessed. Setting a sampler’s value to `i` selects texture image unit number `i`.

The former code has worked and you have "seen" the texture because, if you the uniform variable "transform" is not used, then the uniform is not active and doesn't get a uniform location. So `"ourTexture"` is the only uniform left and likely has the uniform location 0 (`Textureloc == 0`).
Since the value of `"ourTexture"` is not set explicitly, its value is the default value 0.
In this special case the texture unit, the location `Textureloc` and the value of `"ourTexture"` are equal, they are all 0. Your code worked coincidentally.

Since GLSL version 4.2, the texture unit can be set by a [Layout Qualifier (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) within the shader, too. Set a [Binding point](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points), with the texture unit:

```cpp
GLuint unit = 3;
glBindTextureUnit(unit, texture);
```

Vertex shader: `binding = 3` means texture unit 3

```
layout(binding = 3) uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
```

Comment: @HansMicheelsen Yes of course, if the texture is bound to the same unit as the value which is assigned to the sampler uniform. But note there is a limit [`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGet.xml).